# Google visualization treemap - how to create custom text?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am creating a treemap to visualize code complexity in a codebase using the treemap tool provided by the [google visualization api](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap).  By default, the text displayed in each node is the value of the [ID column in the data](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap#Data_Format).  For my data set the ID is very long (file paths) so I'd like to only display the Filename (with the complexity in brackets if possible).
Is there a way to specify an alternative text to display each treemap node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this is quite simple, all you need to do is give a value/format pair for the ID column.

```
[{v:'src/AppCore/3DAnisotropy', f:'3DAnisotropy'},  'src/AppCore',  0,  0],
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out not so easy unless you know that arrayToDataTable() does not support value/format pairs for importing data tables.  Use an alternate DataTable declaration:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', '...');
  data.addColumn('string', '...');
  data.addColumn('number', '...');
  data.addColumn('number', '...');
  data.addRows([
    [{v:'src/AppCore/3DAnisotropy', f:'3DAnisotropy'},  'src/AppCore',  0,  0],
    ...
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where my data source is coming from a csv file. I am using jQuery-csv to turn csv file into an array and then arrayToDataTable to convert it into a DataTable.  As the second poster mentioned, arrayToDataTable does not allow one to specify value/format pairs.  But what I did was to loop through the DataTable records and use the setFormattedValue for the first element of each row to provide the formatted value (taken from another pre-determined column from the array).  That did the trick for me.